# Protractor, internet explorer stops at "initial start page for the WebDriver server."

Tags: angularjs, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver, protractor

I have successfully created and executed test suites in Protractor for Chrome and Firefox. However I am unable to run tests with Internet Explorer. It stops at "initial start page for the WebDriver server" and displays this error in the powershell:

```
[11:02:10] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:02:10] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[11:02:46] E/launcher -
[11:02:46] E/launcher - WebDriverError
at WebDriverError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:521:11)
at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.createSession (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
at createDriver (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:167:33)
at Builder.build (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:632:14)
at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.ts:60:29)
at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
at q.then.then (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
[11:02:46] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

This is my protractor config:

```
// Protractor configuration file
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
multiCapabilities: [
//{ browserName: "chrome" },
{
  browserName: 'internet explorer',
}
//{ browserName: "firefox" }
  ],
  framework: "jasmine2",
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
isVerbose: true,
includeStackTrace: true
  },
  specs: [
"specs/login-spec.js",
  ],
    resultJsonOutputFile: "./Report.json",
};
```

I read tens of posts on StackOverflow but didn't find any solusion to my problem. I have tried to change IE settings but they always go back to its defaults due to corporation setup.
The error stacktrace doesn't give my much information on what's wrong actually. I'm not very familiar with WebDriver source.
Any suggestions? Did anyone face similar problem?

Comment: Things I have tried to do: updating drivers, changing java version, clearing caches, changing capabilities to those I found on stackOverflow, setting path do IE webdriver. None of these things changed anything.

Comment: Whats your IE version?

Comment: I found [this post](http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/) very useful for setting up Protractor on IE - you can skip past the VM steps and just go to the IE config options (starting at step 4)

Comment: Currently there is an issue in protractor (5.1.2) with IE. See this ticket: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4445

Comment: @AshishDeshmukh I have IE 11.09600.18738. Thanks for the link to the issue, I will try to downgrade protractor

Comment: @Gunderson thanks for the link, I actually read it before writing this posts ;)